# onClick event not firing on functional element

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap, react-functional-component

For the life of me I cannot understand why the click event is not firing in my functional component.

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    Collapse,
    Navbar,
    NavbarToggler,
    Nav,
    NavItem,
    NavLink,
} from 'reactstrap';

import classNames from 'classnames';
import img from '../../img/logo/logo-white.svg';

const NavBar = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggle = () => {
        console.log('toggllling', isOpen);
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    };

    return (
        <div
            id="nav-wrap"
            className={classNames({ 'bg-dark-blue': isOpen })}
        >
            <Navbar color="transparent" dark expand="lg" className="container">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img alt="logo light" src={img} />
                </a>
                <NavbarToggler onClick={toggle} />
                <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
                    <Nav className="navbar-nav" navbar>
                        <NavItem className="active">
                            <NavLink href="/">First</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink href="/">second</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink href="/">Thord</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem className="separated">
                            <NavLink href="/">Fourth</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink href="/">fifth</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink href="/" className="btn btn-light">last</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

It's a bit more advanced version of the navbar toggle example from the reactstrap page: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

I can see from the React Devtools that the event is bound to the correct react component. If I replace `toggle` with something that should fire immediately like a function call, then it fires immediately. Yet when I click on the actual button, nothing happens. I even bound a click event to the document to see if there is something hidden above the button and logged out if the event propagates down to correct element - it did. so for the life of me, I cannot figure out why the toggle function never fires and why I never see 'toggllling' in my console. I've tried adding this onClick to any of the other elements in the component also - and it never works anywhere inside the component.

It's probably something really small, that I'm missing here, but for the life of me - I cannot figure out what it is exactly. Not sure what other bits of information could be useful here. Perhaps how I use the component:

```
ready(() => {
    // Example:
    const wrap = document.getElementById('nav-wrap');
    if (wrap) {
        // perform element replacement
        const parent = wrap.parentNode;
        const temp = document.createElement('div');
        render(<NavBar element={wrap} />, temp);
        parent.replaceChild(temp.querySelector('div#nav-wrap'), wrap);
    }
});
```

Edit:

I simplified the component and results are the same - the event is not firing. When I debug it with browser devtools and add breakpoint at mouse click, then I can see that function call ends up in react-dom.development.js `function noop() {}` Why is that?

Comment: There are so many "red flags" in this code, like attaching event on every render and querying the DOM which is an anti-pattern (use ref), if you want it solved you should SIMPLIFY this code to a minimal example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am not sure how your Collapse work, but if it the collapse triggers some listener in your useEffect, then your isOpen becomes false again. I will try by commenting out the useEffect clause, to see if the toggle works

Comment: @DennisVash querying the dom - yup, I could have removed it from the example. The only reason that part exists is to reuse code already in the template which the component eventually replaces. This is not SPA app and should work even without JS. But what do you mean about attaching event in every render? I feel like I'm missing something here. Isn't it the same as here: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/ event is attached in returned code and the code is only re rendered if isopen changes. But I'll try simplifying. That's good suggestion.

Comment: I simplified the component to illustrate what is crucial and debugged it with browser devools. click ends up in react-dom.development.js function noop() {}. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Just make a reproducible example in codesandbox, no one can guess how `NavbarToggler ` implemented

Comment: Nah. Already figured it out. Apparently the too complex replacement mechanics I used screwed up the event propagation somehow. I simplified that too and everything works fine now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure how useful this answer is to the general population. There are not of onClick "not working" questions. Mods - if you see nothing to learn here, please just mark the question for deletion.

So what happened here was that I had this bit of a relic replacement mechanic in my index.js which created the component. I rendered the component inside element not in DOM:

```
        const temp = document.createElement('div');
        render(<NavBar element={wrap} />, temp);
```

And then looked it up and replaced its pure HTML predecessor with the react component. I went for this complex solution, because initially, I just tried to reuse some components. I later changed this logic, but did not go back to just using `render(<NavBar/>, wrap);`, which would have saved me all the trouble of writing this question.

So my own complexity, which I did not reduce on time, created even more overhead and wasted time. So yeah - avoid complexity. That's the lesson here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `setState` with a callback?

```
setIsOpen((prevState) => (
  !prevState
));
```